# FullCalendar Javascript Calendar for EasyAppointments Increase Row Height

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm having a problem increasing the row height of my EasyAppointments calendar and I noticed that the list serve is not active so I was hoping someone has the experience with EasyAppointments or just integrating FullCalendar into framework.

Easy!Appointments is a great Open Source Appointment Scheduler but as you can see in the attachment, I changed the booking time to 15 minute intervals and now the event height is too tiny to see clearly. I tried traversing the CSS tree and couldn't find an option and would even delve into the javascript to increase the row size if I knew enough.
[image]

In the Monday 8/31 10am time slot it's so tiny and hard to click on for the end-user wanting to donate their time.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:
Temporary solution until I find out what the best way is...

```
Possible Fix: Line 1179 in file /assets/ext/jquery-fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css

.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
    height: 3.0em; /* Orig 1.5em */
    border-bottom: 0; /* each cell is responsible for its top border */
}
```

Comment: Either increase the height of the calendar, or make the slot duration smaller. Not sure what version of fullCalendar you're using but you can find information for the latest version of those features at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration . In the top right corner of the page there's a drop-down where you can change the version to get the correct documentation for your version (although there may be little difference in many cases).

Comment: @ADyson Thought I had it when I changed line 16931 in /assets/ext/jquery-fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js   to this.slotDuration = '00:15:00'; but that only changed the height of each slot but then when you click in a calendar cell, it was associated with the wrong time. :-/ I posted it as an answer then deleted it when I realized it was not completely correct.

Comment: Stop changing the fullCalendar source code and start using the options provided and listed in the documentation

Comment: Thanks understandable @ADyson. Wish it was better but the documentation is limited. FAQ is extremely limited, and help is sparse for Easy!Appointments with one hack listed for an old version which doesn't work anymore including problems with the Google Group for community support.

Comment: I was thinking of the fullCalendar documentation actually (as per the links I provided above) - their documentation is reasonably good. If this easyappointments is based on fullCalendar then it should have all the same options, I'd expect.